# Reemplazar una subcadena en una cadena en python

Tags: python, string, regex

Quiero reemplazar por "fooBAR" por "FooBar", la letra inicial la he resuelto, pero no encuentro cómo cambiar "BAR" (subcadena) por "Bar". He probado con cosas así pero no sirve.

```
def repl_func(match):
        if match == True:
            return str.capitalize()
    
    s = re.sub(r"[A-Z]{2,}", repl_func, s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El caso es más simple. Cuando se usa

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string)¶
```

y `repl` es una función, la función es llamada sólo cuando se encuentra un calce de `pattern` dentro del `string`. La función recibirá un `match object` que nos describe el patrón encontrado (`BAR`, en este caso). El texto mismo del patrón encontrado está dado por `group(0)`.

```
def repl_func(match):
    return str.capitalize(match.group(0))
```

Esta función capitalizara cualquier secuencia de dos o más mayúsculas.

#### Demo

```
import re

def repl_func(match):
    return str.capitalize(match.group(0))

tests = ["fooBAR", "FooBaR", "FOOBAR", "foobar"]

for test in tests:
    x = re.sub(r"[A-Z]{2,}", repl_func, test)
    print(test, x)
```

produce:

```
fooBAR fooBar
FooBaR FooBaR
FOOBAR Foobar
foobar foobar

Process finished with exit code 0
```